# azure iot device to cloud messaging

Tags: c#, azure, iot

I want to write a console application that writes device message to the cloud. I have written a cloud2-device application using IOT hub and preconfig all of my Hub device ID and works.

Here is my sample code to connect-2-cloud-message using C# in visual studio.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Diagnostics.Tracing;
using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client;

namespace Device2CloudApp
{
    class Program
    {

        // private our own fields for connection to IOT.

        private DeviceClient deviceClient;


        // use the device specific connection string.

        private const string IOT_HUB_CONN_STRING = "HostName=eNstaHub.azure-devices.net;DeviceId=GcobaniNumber1;SharedAccessKey="";
        private const string IOT_HUB_DEVICE = "GcobaniNumber1";
        private const string IOT_HUB_DEVICE_LOCATION = "West US";


        /*
         *  We calling all method inside the constructor for memory allocation. 
         */
       public  Program ()
        {

            SendMessageToIOTHubAsync(deviceClient).Wait();

        }

        private async Task SendMessageToIOTHubAsync(DeviceClient deviceClient)
        {
            try
            {
                var payload = "{" +
                "\"deviceId\":\"" + IOT_HUB_DEVICE + "\", " +
                "\"location\":\"" + IOT_HUB_DEVICE_LOCATION + "\", " +
                "\"localTimestamp\":\"" + DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime() + "\"" +
                "}";

                var msg = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload));
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("\t{0} > Sending message:[{1}]", DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime(), payload);
                await deviceClient.SendEventAsync(msg);
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("!!!" + ex.Message);
            }
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DeviceClient deviceClient = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(IOT_HUB_CONN_STRING);

            // creating a Constructor here for method declarion.

            Program prg = new Program();
        }
    }
}
```

On my console its not connection to the cloud-IOT hub;
It throws an System.NullreferenceException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work as following code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Diagnostics.Tracing;
using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client;

namespace Device2CloudApp
{
    class Program
    {
        // private our own fields for connection to IOT.
        private DeviceClient deviceClient;    

        // use the device specific connection string.

        private const string IOT_HUB_CONN_STRING = "HostName=eNstaHub.azure-devices.net;DeviceId=GcobaniNumber1;SharedAccessKey="";
        private const string IOT_HUB_DEVICE = "GcobaniNumber1";
        private const string IOT_HUB_DEVICE_LOCATION = "West US";


        /*
         *  We calling all method inside the constructor for memory allocation. 
         */
        public  Program ()
        {

            DeviceClient deviceClient = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(IOT_HUB_CONN_STRING);
            SendMessageToIOTHubAsync(deviceClient).Wait();

        }

        private async Task SendMessageToIOTHubAsync(DeviceClient deviceClient)
        {
            try
            {
                var payload = "{" +
                "\"deviceId\":\"" + IOT_HUB_DEVICE + "\", " +
                "\"location\":\"" + IOT_HUB_DEVICE_LOCATION + "\", " +
                "\"localTimestamp\":\"" + DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime() + "\"" +
                "}";

                var msg = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload));
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("\t{0} > Sending message:[{1}]", DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime(), payload);
                await deviceClient.SendEventAsync(msg);
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("!!!" + ex.Message);
            }
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // creating a Constructor here for method declarion.

            Program prg = new Program(deviceClient);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks team, first example did the trick i had managed to connect from device to cloud message. TelemetryData point is good constant field to use in your class. As it send reference to your IOT Hub for monitoring. I exclude other fields like temperature etc as were not part of my scope to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have a local `deviceClient` in the `main` method which is not the one used when communicating with Azure.

Remove that one, and create the instance that you have in the class instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this .Hope it helps.

Declare the constants first.

```
    private const string DeviceKey = "your secret key";
    private const string DeviceId = "DeviceName";
```

And then create a connection string based on SymmetricKey

```
     _deviceClient = DeviceClient.Create(IotHubUri, new 
     DeviceAuthenticationWithRegistrySymmetricKey(DeviceId, DeviceKey), TransportType.Mqtt);
```

Sample code of Simulator:

```
   using System;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client;
   using Newtonsoft.Json;
   namespace SimulatedDevice
   {
   class Program
    {
    private const string IotHubUri = "YourHubName.azure-devices.net";
    private const string DeviceKey = "Secret Key";
    private const string DeviceId = "DeviceId";
    private const double MinVoltage = 40;
    private const double MinTemperature = 10;
    private const double MinHumidity = 50;
    private static readonly Random Rand = new Random();
    private static DeviceClient _deviceClient;
    private static int _messageId = 1;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Simulated device\n");
        _deviceClient = DeviceClient.Create(IotHubUri, new DeviceAuthenticationWithRegistrySymmetricKey(DeviceId, DeviceKey), TransportType.Mqtt);
        _deviceClient.ProductInfo = "Simulated_Client";

        SendDeviceToCloudMessagesAsync();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static async void SendDeviceToCloudMessagesAsync()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var currentVoltage = MinVoltage + Rand.NextDouble() * 15;
            var currentTemperature = MinTemperature + Rand.NextDouble() * 20;
            var currentHumidity = MinHumidity + Rand.NextDouble() * 25;

            var telemetryDataPoint = new
            {

                deviceId = DeviceId,
                timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow,
                Temperature = currentTemperature,
                Humidity = currentHumidity,
                Voltage = currentVoltage,

            };
            var messageString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(telemetryDataPoint);
            var message = new Message(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(messageString));

            await _deviceClient.SendEventAsync(message);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} > Sending message: {1}", DateTime.Now, 
             messageString);

            await Task.Delay(2000);
          }
         }

      }
     }
```